# What are the current fastest algorithms for basic mathematical operations?

Tags: asymptotics

In other words, what algorithms have been demonstrated to have the fastest big O notation time/asymptotic complexity for, assuming two real numbers $x$ and $y$:

- $x + y$
- $x \times y$
- $\frac xy$
- $x-y$
- $x^y$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations
I think this article will be quite helpful

Comment: We expect you to do some research on your own before asking. If you had done that, you'd realise that you're basically asking us to rewrite a Wikipedia page for you, which isn't a productive use of anyone's time.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Assuming only one algorithm exists for each category, then how much broad would that be, really?

Comment: @TheBitByte It would mean that a good answer would be a detailed discussion of five different algorithms. Already, that's too much, but it would be even worse if different algorithms have best performance for different sized inputs (e.g., for _matrix_ multiplication, there are algorithms that are faster than their competitors for huge matrices but slower for smaller ones). And it's all already on Wikipedia anyway.

Comment: @DavidRicherby So if I posted it as five different questions, would that be a good thing? Obviously that seems a bit spammy hence why I chose not to do it. When I combined them into a single question, it's too broad. What do I do, then?

Comment: @TheBitByte Thanks for trying to not be spammy -- that's definitely appreciated. But your question is already answered on Wikipedia.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Wikipedia seems to be presenting a list of algorithms, not saying which of them is the fastest.

Comment: @TheBitByte That's precisely because of the situation I suggested with matrix multiplication. Even for multiplication of integers (which I should have used as my example instead), there are multiple algorithms, each of which is fastest under different circumstances.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Do you mean that generic algorithm that is optimized for all integers isn't possible?

Comment: @TheBitByte I've no idea, but we don't know one today. Bear in mind, though, that most of our analysis of complexity is asymptotic: it only applies for big enough inputs. Suppose $X$ takes (exactly) $n^2$ steps and $Y$ takes (exactly) $1000n$ steps, for inputs of size $n$. Well, if $n$ is really big, then $Y$ is faster. But if $n<1000$, then $X$ is faster. In reality, it won't always be $1000n$ because the constant will depend on the hardware. This means that benchmarking becomes important and any full answer includes a lot of "it depends".